# How to display data using v-for and CSS Grid

Tags: css, vue.js, css-grid

I'm struggling to display my data from Vuex using CSS GRID. Everything looks messy.

I have two columns. The first column displays labels:

```
{{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].label}}
```

Second one for values

```
{{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].value}}
```

Here is my Html:

```
.display-data
    span(
      v-for='(item, idx) in $store.state.stepOne.textfield'
      :key='idx'
    ) {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].label}}
    span(
      v-for='(item, idx) in $store.state.stepOne.textfield'
      :key='idx'
    ) {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].value}}
```

CSS:

```
.display-data
    display: grid
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr
    grid-template-rows: repeat(25, 1fr)
    grid-gap: 15px 15px
    margin: 0 auto 50px auto
    width: 700px
    justify-items: center
```

I want to make the same as in the picture below:
[image]

Comment: What does "looks messy" mean.  What is your HTML?

Comment: @Paulie_D Thats my html. I'm using pug

`.display-data
    span(
      v-for='(item, idx) in $store.state.stepOne.textfield'
      :key='idx'
    ) {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].label}}
    span(
      v-for='(item, idx) in $store.state.stepOne.textfield'
      :key='idx'
    ) {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].value}}`

Comment: It must **output** *actual* HTML at some point though...right?

Comment: @Paulie_D right

Comment: So *that's* what we need to see. In other words, a [mcve] of this being "messed up"

Answer (score 0):

i have **no idea** how to write pug code but you should be able to somehow write something like this :

```
.display-data( v-for='(item, idx) in $store.state.stepOne.textfield' :key='idx' ) 
    span {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].label}}
    span {{$store.state.stepOne.textfield[idx].value}}
```

something like this could work